# Can we open dialog within a dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a button which on clicking opens jquery dialog. Inside that jquery dialog i have another button which on clicking should open yet another dialog. The 1st dialog is open correctly but the 2nd dialog is not opening. Can anybody tell me what can be the problem?

Both the dialogs are non modal. Still, the 1st one gets opened but the 2nd one doesn't.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you're doing? (Offhand, I'm not sure it's possible...but it would help to know what you've already tried.)

Comment: Well i am using Codeignite. There is one OK button which on clicking makes a ajax call and loads one php file inside that dialog. That php file has one another button which on clicking shows a simple dialog. Does that help? The code is actually of live application so posting it here won't make sense anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible. I do it all the time. Please post some code so we can see what's wrong.

Make sure you have the "stack" property set to true, like so:

```
var DialogOptions = {
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    stack: true
};

$('selector').dialog(DialogOptions);
```

description from jquery documentation:

> Specifies whether the dialog will
>   stack on top of other dialogs. This
>   will cause the dialog to move to the
>   front of other dialogs when it gains
>   focus.

**Code examples**

Initialize a dialog with the stack option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ stack: false });
```

Get or set the stack option, after init.

```
//getter
var stack = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "stack" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "stack", false );
```

Comment: ok posting sample code in few mins time. Please bear with me.

Comment: i swear to god sometimes i wonder what's up with people, i told you to look into the options provided by the plugin 10 min before this answer and i got 2 neg votes for it, then 5min still before this answer i posted a link to stack... and what do i get another neg vote on my answer, well you got the answer you searched for at least good for you

Answer (score 4):

I dont know what a jquery dialog is but my guess here would be that the code is targeting the **same** block(element) when showing/creating a dialog, the dialog might have some options where you can set how it opens your dialog according to your needs look through documentation and you'll probably be good to go

look into options such as 
[**stack**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-stack)

if you don't post any code you cant expect anymore aid then this

Answer (score 0):

I doit all the time:

```
function createParentDialog()
{
 $('#parentDialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 220,
                width: 380,
                resizable: false,
                modal: false,
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function(){
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                         },
                    "Show ChildDialog": function(){ 
                          showChildDialog();
                         }
               }
               });
   function createChildDialog()
   {
     $('#childDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 220,
            width: 380,
            resizable: false,
            modal: false});
   }

$(document).ready(function () {
        createChildDialog();
        createParentDialog();
    });
```